# How to display Under Line of selected page in header Menu

Tags: php, html, css

[image: this is header of my website.]

I want to show under line of Selected Page in header Menu. And The Header is Comman File For All. is Header.php

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
   <li class="<?php (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "index.php") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="<?php (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "jobsList") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="jobsList.php?id=3">Bank Job</a></li>
<li class="<?php (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "boardResult") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="boardResult.php">Board Result</a></li>
<li class="<?php (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "AdmitCard") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="AdmitCard.php">Admit Card</a></li>
<li class="<?php (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "AnsKey") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="AnsKey.php">Answer Key </a></li>
<li class="<?php (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "TimeTable") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="TimeTable.php">Time Table </a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Check if the current URL matches the link

Comment: i don't know how can i do it,

Comment: how can i check sir ???

Comment: add border using inline css to solve this

Comment: thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you can use PHP.

You can check the current URI on the URL and if it matches then add the class 'active' on the desired `li` to add the underline style :)

This would do the job:

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
    <li class="<?php echo (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "index") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "jobsList") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="jobsList.php?id=3">Bank Job</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "boardResult") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="boardResult.php">Board Result</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "AdmitCard") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="AdmitCard.php">Admit Card</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "AnsKey") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="AnsKey.php">Answer Key </a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "TimeTable") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="TimeTable.php">Time Table </a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Or you can try

```
<li class="<?= (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "index") !== false) ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav li.active a {
  /* Apply the styles you want on the active anchors*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: @Meenapatel now it should work, sorry I'm currently a little sleepy and I miss few elements.

Comment: class not added. why ?

Comment: I aprove @B.Desai edit, it was another stupid mistake, I would go sleep :)

Comment: check now @Meenapatel

Comment: check page name with id please

Comment: @Meenapatel you can check it with $_GET['id'] along with and condition.

Comment: @Meenapatel we are not here to do all your work, we can offer you a proper way to solve your problem and check for errors on your code, but the rest is from you, I think we show you already how to add the active class on the li, now it's your turn, in case you get stuck create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `border-bottom` property sample here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}
li {
float: left;
}
 li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
 }
li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
}
.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <ul>
 <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: visit my page : http://fbfunzone.com/jobPortalplus/index.php 
and i want css same as on hover